# Android showing a transparent activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a transparent activity which is used for getting an `AlertDialog`. This `AlertDialog` appears anytime my app gets a push notification(foreground or background). But when the `AlertDialog` appears and if there is an another `Activity` in the background `AlertDialog` appears on top of this `Activity`. I want to see only the `AlertDialog` when user taps the notification.

Here is the code that shows the `AlertDialog` when app is foreground

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialogActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(dialogIntent);
MainActivity.this.finish();
```

And when app is background i use `PendingIntent`

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialogActivity.class);
final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                mContext,
                0,
                dialogIntent ,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        );
```

Is there a solution for showing only `AlertDialog` when user taps the notification ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can open  a pop up using alert dialog box using custom layout. I have a code to show pop up using alert dialog box custom made

Comment: Here is your solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/2700683/6676466

Comment: @ApoorvMehrotra there is no problem with opening a pop up.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? If you are on the home and this activity is opened from the notification - show the transparent activity with the dialog over the home, correct? And if you're in your app or any other app - you want to stop it and show the dialog?!

Comment: @Tartar so you want that code ?

Comment: @Seishin i want to see only the transparent activity.

Comment: I dont think you guys did read my question properly. I got the pop up already. I want only the pop up to be shown(not any other activity underneath of the pop up) when device gets the notification.

Comment: @Tartar, if you app is present, you can finish all the activities in the activity stack, but if another app is present... It will not be possible to do it that easily.

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate below the setContentView put this line

getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));